# Error 401 - But htpasswd valid

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-401

I have a strange bug since few day.

We made up a wordpress website on our server ofr a customer.
Same process as our previous customer, but for this only, there is a bug.

All our site are htpasswd protected.

For this site, i got a 401 error randomly (after 20 minutes, after une hours, ...).
The site appears properly, but i got 

`Authorization Required
This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required`

at the top of my page...

If i disable the htpasswd, the error go away. When i enabled again, the error will show randomly after a few time...So, it's not coming from a plugin. It's related to our server...
The error log show nothing, and here is my htaccess :

```
AuthUserFile /home/NDD.fr/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic
#<Limit GET>
Require valid-user
#</Limit>
```

Any idea ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
```

And check that `/home/NDD.fr/.htpasswd` is readable by the `apache2` or `www-data` user.

(If you don't know how to do that, run `ls -la /home/NDD.fr/ | grep htpasswd` on your server.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I remove the line and check the right, but no change.
But, i created again the site with the same process, and it seems to work...
I'll see...
Thanks !